# Set default value in Moodle form

Tags: php, forms, moodle

In our **Moodle** installation there is the plugin **Assignemnt**, where we get the **list** with all participants in the course, so we can grade them, based on the assignment. 
In the **table** there are **by default** always shown **10** people and there are the options, where we can choose to see **all** at once, **10**, **20**, **50** or **100** per page.

The code is in `gradingoptionsform.php:`

```
 $options = array(-1=>get_string('all'), 10=>'10', 20=>'20', 50=>'50', 100=>'100');
 $mform->addElement('select', 'perpage', get_string('assignmentsperpage', 'assign'), $options, $dirtyclass);
```

I tried with `$mform-setDefault('perpage', 'all')` but it didn't worked.

What I am missing?

In `gradingtable.php` there is:

```
class assign_grading_table extends table_sql implements renderable {
    /** @var assign $assignment */
    private $assignment = null;
    /** @var int $perpage */
    private $perpage = 10;
```

Which doesn't seem to have any influence on the default value?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set:

```
$mform->setDefault('perpage', -1);
```

EDIT:
It seems that this setting gets overwritten by php code. Search in mod/assign/locallib.php :

```
$perpage = get_user_preferences('assign_perpage', 10);
```

Change is to:

```
$perpage = get_user_preferences('assign_perpage', -1);
```

Comment: It should work, but it isn't. I tried even with changin the version of the plugin.

Comment: Did you try edit version of answer? That should work.